# Create a GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY identifier field in a PostgreSQL 14+ database table using Django 4.1.x

Tags: django, postgresql

I would like Django 4.1.x (I'm using `4.1.3` at the time of writing) to create a PostgreSQL (v14+) table for which the identifier, `id`, has to be created as if I were creating the table with this SQL snippet for the `id` field: `id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

This would normally ends up on a schema like this in PG 15:

```bash
$ pg_dump --table table_foo --schema-only -d postgres

-- multiple SET statements here (...)

CREATE TABLE public.table_foo (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(1024) NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.table_foo OWNER TO postgres;

ALTER TABLE public.table_foo ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.table_foo_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.table_foo
    ADD CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Here's my current model in Django:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        verbose_name=_("Name"),
        null=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

It actually creates this table (`makemigrations`/`migrate`) with the following `ALTER` statement instead:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.table_foo ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME public.table_foo_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);
```

How can I achieve that, if possible?

I cannot find anything about the `identity` PostgreSQL type in the doc:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#bigautofield

On PostgreSQL identity field:
https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns-explained